# Move a Sprite Kit Physics Body to where the user touched without going through

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, physics

I have a sprite kit physics body that I want to be controlled by touching by moving it towards the location where the user touched in touchesBegan and touchesMoved. I have tried the SKAction move and let's just saw it didn't suit my purposes. I have tried applyImpulse and it suited my purpose, but each time it overshot cause the velocity cause it to go through the location every time, and if I made new locations the object went flying around back and forth. I would like it to follow the current touch somewhat fast, and not slowly crawl toward the user's finger. Is there an easy way to make the object follow the touch when the user is touching and stop moving when the user lets go that will go well with the psrite kit physics engine? I want the object to bounce other objects off it but not bounce itself.

Comment: I have also tried setting the location of the object directly to the touch location and that did not respond well with the physics either. What I meant by that is it didn't make the other objects bounce off of it.

Comment: Show your code for the SKAction. What do you mean "it didn't suit my purposes"? What about it was wrong?

Comment: there's no easy way, there's only lots of tweaking (impulses/forces)

Answer (score 1):

Add a few things:

1. a Boolean flag to set whether or not the Sprite has been assigned a new location
2. a CGPoint storing the new desired location
3. a method that checks if the location of the sprite is close enough to the CGPoint to be considered as arrived

When the touch is issued, store the point and set the Boolean to YES then initiate the force on the sprite.

Inside the update method put a call to that checker method that is called if the Boolean you made is YES.

If that check returns true, set the velocity to zero (or otherwise stop the sprite how you see fit) and set the Boolean back to NO so that check method stops firing.